# vim compiler error font when install plug vim

Tags: vim

I have an error while installing Vim, if you know how to recover please guide me! Thanks you!
[image]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the error?   Please describe specifically.

Comment: There is no error, here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the vim-airline plugin for a status line.

The `[No Name]` string is the name of the current buffer.  If you opened up vim without an argument, it opens up a buffer that has no name until you save it.

The `[dos]` string is probably showing the filetype of your buffer (I don't know why the default is dos though).

The funny characters between NORMAL and [No Name] are where vim-airline puts powerline font characters.  If your font can't support these characters, then turn off powerline characters with this in your ~/.vimrc.

```
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```